# Proving this map to be quotient map( Closed /open sets in more than 1 dimensions)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let p :$ \mathbb{R}^2 \to [0,\infty)$ by p((x,y))= $x^2 +y^2$ and suppose $[0,\infty)$ has the subspace topology induced by usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that p is a quotient map.

There is a theorem tahtif p is continuous ,surjective, open or closed then p is quotient map.

I was trying to use this result here but the problem is that I am not sure on how to prove that If map is closed/open or not and that is arising as it's a 2-variable map.

> So, can you please help me with the how maps are proved to be Open / closed in more than one dimensions? It will be hard if I take a open/closed map and try to find its range and checking the set wheter it's open or not?

So, Can you please tell of a more elegant stratergy?

OR If there is a different but less brute method of proving the map to be quotient map that is also welcome.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map $f$ is open if the image of any open set $\mathcal{O}$ is open. I.e., if $f(\mathcal{O})$ is open.

The standard open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are of the form $B_{r}((a,b)) = \{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2<r^2 \}$. I.e., a ball of radius r about the point $(a,b)$. These form a basis for the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it suffices to check that $f(B_r(a,b))$ is open for any choice of $r$, $a$ and $b$.

Now, the map $f$ takes in a point $(x,y)$ and outputs $x^2+y^2$. That is, the length from the origin (modulus) squared. So, $f$ will take in all the points of $B_r(a,b)$ and output all the possible lengths squared. So, we need to find the range of lengths. This is determined by the point in $B_r(a,b)$ closest to the origin and the point in $B_r(a,b)$ farthest from the origin.

These points are easy to find. Take a line passing through the origin and the point (a,b). This line will intersect the circle in two spots: $P_1$ and $P_2$. Let's say that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are distances $r_1$ and $r_2$ from the origin respectively. Without loss of generality, assume that $r_1<r_2$.

Now, I claim that $f(B_r(a,b)) = (r_1,r_2)$, which is indeed open. Why might that be?